# Connect devuelve error Test tokens are not allowed

Tags: mercadopago

estoy desarrollando la integración con MercadoPago Connect en mi marketplace siguiendo la documentación de:
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/mp-applications/

Obtengo el token de usuario vendedor perfectamente.
Pero cuando intento crear una preferencia de pago utilizando ese token obtengo siempre el mensaje de error:
"Test tokens are not allowed"

Estoy usando el modo sandbox en todos los casos, y no encuentro en la documentación ningún paso que me pueda estar saltando.

Para conectar el usuario he probado con usuarios personales de MercadoPago y con usuarios de prueba generados por Curl.

A alguno le ha pasado esto antes? Es acaso que solo se puede hacer en modo productivo?

Comment: Estas usando tu token de Test para la inicialización del SDK ?

Comment: Los lineamientos del sitio indican que se debe evitar el uso de etiquetas en el título. Referencia [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontre el problema:

Si usas checkout básico tenes que usar "Mercado Pago Application" para obtener las credenciales de tus usuarios vendedores, esto se hace usando tu Client_ID y Client_secret.

Si usas checkout personalizado tenes que usar "Mercado Pago Connect" para obtener las credenciales de tu usuario, que se hacer con un Token de test primero y luego de producción.

Yo estaba intentando usar el checkout básico con un token de test obtenido usando "MercadoPago Connect".